# Excluding variables with grep in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following. Of course mine is a lot bigger with much more variables. I want to compute some stuff, for which I need to choose specific variables. For example I want to choose the variables T_H_01 - T_H_03, but I don't want to have T_H_G and T_H_S within. I tried doing it with grep, but I don't know how to tell the grep function to take all the "T_H" Items but exclude specific variables such as T_H_G and T_H_S.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
T_H_01 T_H_02 T_H_03 T_H_G T_H_S 
5 1 2 1 5 
3 1 3 3 4 
2 1 3 1 3  
4 2 5 5 3 
5 1 4 1 2 
")

df[,grep("T_H.",names(df))]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want columns `T_H_` followed by a number, then simply phrase that in your call to `grep`:

```r
df[, grep("^T_H_\\d+$", names(df))]
```

If instead you want to phrase the search as explicitly excluding `T_H_G` and `T_H_S`, then you could use a negative lookahead for that:

```r
df[, grep("^T_H_(?![GS]$).+$", names(df), perl=TRUE)]
```

Comment: Your second `grepl` statement is missing a `perl = TRUE`: `df[, grep("^T_H_(?![GS]$).+$", names(df), perl = TRUE)]`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
ex <- c('T_H_G', 'T_H_S' )

df[,grepl("T_H.", names(df)) & !names(df) %in% ex]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach, to filter out not useful column:

```
df[,grep("T_H.",names(df))[!(grep("T_H.",names(df)) %in% c(grep("T_H_G",names(df)),grep("T_H_S",names(df))))]]
  T_H_01 T_H_02 T_H_03
1      5      1      2
2      3      1      3
3      2      1      3
4      4      2      5
5      5      1      4
```

If you have a generic pattern to exclude specific columns, you can improve the grep condition with it.